# ErrorProne Varargs doesn't agree for overridden method VS SonarQube java:S923 Do not use varargs

Tags: java, sonarqube, errorprone

*What I am trying to achieve:*

Write a code `public final class MyService implements CommandLineRunner {` which complies with both ErrorProne and SonarQube.

Here is the code snippet:

```
public final class MyService implements CommandLineRunner {

@Override
    public void run(final String... args) {
        doSomething();
    }

@Override
    public void run(final String[] args) {
        doSomething();
    }
```

*What did I try:*

If I use the `public void run(final String[] args) {`, SonarQube will flag java:S923 Functions should not be defined with a variable number of arguments, ErrorProne is happy.

If I use the `public void run(final String... args) {` ErrorProne will flag the Varargs doesn't agree for overridden method while SonarQube is happy.

*Question:*

Is there a way to make both of them happy with some smarter code?

Comment: Doesn't seem like there's anything you can do. Just exclude the method from your rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove 'final' in final String... args. ErrorProne may be complaining about mismatching with run method from SpringBoot CLR where it has no 'final' keyword.